# excel easy way to replace period-"." to blank but not touch numbers with decimals

Tags: excel

My data looks like this

```
bucket  Nov-16  Dec-16     Jan-17
0          0      0.0398     0
1          0      0.03981    0
2          0      0.039818   .
3      0.0594     0.03981    .
4      0.0694       .        .
```

if i use find and replace functions even the decimal points are affected. Is there an easy way to replace only the period symbol and not the decimal periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to use Excel's Find and Replace dialogue, check the "Match entire cell contents" box and leave the "Replace with" field empty.

Answer (score 1):

Can’t test this as on a smartphone, but something like the following could work in a helper column

```
=if(istext(A1), substitute(".",""),A1)
```

Then copy and paste special values back into the original cells.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub DotKiller()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If Not r.HasFormula Then
                If Not IsNumeric(r.Value) Then
                    r.Value = Replace(r.Value, ".", "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: @Bathsheba  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your data are located in the range A1:D6 then use the *array formula*

```
{=IF(A1:D6=".","",A1:D6)}
```

somewhere else on the workbook. Use Ctrl + Shift + Return to enter an array formula, having selected an appropriate range first.

Answer (score 0):

To replace dots with the appearance of empty cells and in the process show a consistent number of decimal places custom formatting is easy:

```
    0.000000 ;[red](0.000000);0;
```

provided not applied to the header row.